# How to delete virtual environment completely on Docker?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to make a Django and Postgre container using docker-compose. I followed this tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/.

I am using Windows and executed the following command:

> docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample .

After that, I modified my Dockerfile to include some apt-get update

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libgdal-dev

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /usr/src/app/
```

I deleted the created composeexample folder and data folder, and run the command again.

> docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample .

This time. I get the following error:

> CommandError: /usr/src/app/manage.py already exists. Overlaying a
> project into an existing directory won't replace conflicting files.
> ERROR: 1

Somehow Docker thinks the files still exist from the 1st execution. Even if I change the name of the parent directory to change the container name, I still get the error.

How can I remove the environment completely from my 1st execution?

Comment: What contains your `/usr/src/app` upon docker execution is complete? It looks like there is conflict with something that is not expected to be here

Comment: After a look at the tuto, you may have some local files (i.e. where you run `docker-compose up` from which conflicts with `manage.py`. I would suggest you run `docker-compose up` from an empty directory.

Comment: @Jib the container for the web tho isnt running because of the error so I cannot SSH. Empty directory with a different component or images?

Comment: @Jib its still error on a different directory: `python: can't open file '/usr/src/app/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the tutorial you followed, the docker-compose.yml declares a volume to be mounted into the docker container:

```
  web:
...
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
...
```

In your docker file, you copy the content of the local directory into the declared working directory `/usr/src/app`.

Here is what I would suggest:

1. change the place of the resource files to be used for building your docker container.

In my projects I usually rely on this directory structure:

```
web/
  - Dockerfile
  + build-src/
    ... the needed files to build the container image ..
    - requirements.txt
  + data/
    .. the data files and folders needed/resulting of running ..
```

2. change the docker file to something like this:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libgdal-dev

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./web/build-src/requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Upon successful build, you will get an docker container image which embeds all the necessary requirements to run your Python application. Do not build the container yet ;)

NOTE: each docker command creates a new layer. When you execute a `RUN` to install a new package, you should rather want it to be "oneline" and remove the temporary files which may take up some disk space for nothing. The following command will result in the same as yours, but will require less storage disk space and will generate smaller intermediate layer images:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        libgdal-dev && \
    rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists
```

3. change the docker compose `web` part to something like this:

```
  web:
...
    build:
      context: web
    volumes:
      - ./web/data:/usr/src/app
...
```

4. Rebuild and run your container(s) from top project directory:

```bash
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose up
```

In case this does not solve your issue, it will (at least) help you isolate build files from execution file (i.e.: files which are required for building the container image from files which are either used or produced/changed by the container).